# Issue with wordpress calling query to database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Hey guys so I am trying to access my database which is within wordpress to get some field values and I tried doing just straight up PDO style but it seems to not work so I went into wordpress codex and did their way to call things, but still no success!

CODE:

```
/***GET USERNAME***/
            global $current_user;
            get_currentuserinfo();
            $accusername = $current_user->user_login ;
            /******SEE IF FIRST TIME DISCOUNT CODE BEEN USED*******/
            $wpdb->query( 
                        $wpdb->prepare( 
                "
                        SELECT firsttime_discount
                        FROM $wpdb->users
                        WHERE user-login = %d

                ",
                    $accusername 
                                       )
                        );
                /******CHECK IT******/
                echo"working";
            $wpdb->query('query');
            echo"working";
            if ($checkFTDiscount->firsttimediscount != 1){
                    $validFTDiscount = 1;
            }
            else{
                $validFTDiscount = 0;
                echo"wori"; 
            }
```

So it's suppose to go in and see if the value for discount code is set to 1 in the wp_user area, and if not just set a value to 0.

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can use $wpdb, you must declare `global $wpdb;`

```
    global $current_user, $wpdb;
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Further down the road, when you start doing PHP OOP, keep in mind that you in your constructor class you can add `global $wpdb; $this->wpdb = $wpdb;` to avoid re-declaring it every function within the object. This is something I didn't find out until today.